# invalid PasswordChangeForm

Tags: django, authentication, view, change-password

Heyho,

I created a model `Profile` with a `OnetoOneField` to `User`. In `account_settings` view I want to either give the possibility to change the profile information or reset the password. Changing Profile-Information works fine, but when I try to change the password, my `PasswordChangeForm` is always invalid. Can somebody tell me where my mistake is?

Here's the view:

```
def account_settings(request, id):
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'passwordchange' in request.POST:
        user_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, prefix='password')
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
        return redirect('profile', user.id)
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'profilechange' in request.POST:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile,prefix='profil')
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
        return redirect('account_settings',user.id)
        #else:
            #messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, prefix='password')
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile,prefix='profil')
        return render(request, 'app/accountform.html', {'profileuser': user,'user_form': user_form,'profile_form': profile_form})
```

the template:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="profile-content">
    <form  method="post" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ profile_form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit" name="profilechange">Änderungen speichern</button>
    </form>
    <form  method="post" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ user_form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit" name="passwordchange">Passwort ändern</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'profile' user.profile.id %}" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Abbrechen</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `POST` data to the form, which is why it is failing to validate. You need to pass the `POST` data when initialising it:

```
user_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, data=request.POST, prefix='password')
if user_form.is_valid():
    # This should work now
```